# Ignoring directory when doing a SVN commit in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am currently using Eclipse (Indigo Service Release 1) for Android development. When I do try to "commit" changes which I make to a specific project, I am prompted to commit all the files under "bin" directory.

I do not want to commit it and a simpler solution is to un-check them all every time I commit. However this is getting annoying and I was wondering if there is a permanent fix to it.

I tried :

Preferences -> Team -> Ignore Resources -> Add Pattern with "bin" as the added pattern.

However it doesn't really provide a permanent solution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323121/eclipse-svn-ignore-bin) might help

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to set the svn:ignore property.

From within Eclipse this is best achieved by right clicking on the `bin` directory (in Package Explorer/Navigator).  Then select Team -> Add to svn:ignore and in the subsequent dialog select "Resource(s) by name".

When you next commit the project the newly set svn:ignore properties will be committed too and the `bin` directory (and contents) will be permanently excluded.

Steps:

1. Turn off automatic build and clean the project.
2. If the directory is already committed, do Team -> revert, delete it (deleting in Eclipse will do an `svn delete`) and then commit this change.
3. Now recreate the directory (running your build may do this)
4. Then on the directory select Team -> Add to svn:ignore and in the subsequent dialog select "Resource(s) by name".

Comment: Strangely enough I do not have svn:ignore highlighted. So I went to folder -> right click -> set property -> svn:ignore (which I chose from the drop-down). Still no effect.

Do you happen to know why is it not even highlighted? Or presumably am I doing something very stupid? :)

Comment: Has the bin directory already been committed?  If so you must first do an SVN delete, then commit and then try the svn:ignore on the unversion-controlled file (it should have a ? on the icon)  The fact that you're able to access the svn properties for that directory suggests it's already been committed.

Comment: Ah, I got it fixed. It was not showing up since there still was a .svn file lurking in the deep. Thanks a zillion!

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:

1.In File Explorer, right-click on SVN project folder-name
2.Click on "SVN Commit..."
3.A "commit" window will appear
 
4.Right-click on the folder/file that you want to ignore
5.Click on Add to ignore list
6.Select the folder/file
7.Commit the "property change" to SVN

Voila!

Answer (score -1):

if you can not add files or Directories section in the " svn: ignore property "
One solution is to not hide the eclipse view all files or folder not committer .
right click on the folder and then select delete from view